# Error while creating my first project related to "Gradle"

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, synchronization

I create a brand new project, and immediately afterwards the synchronization with Gradle fails.

These are the type of errors I see (this is just a fraction, there are many more).

A problem occurred configuring root project 'My Application'. > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.    > Failed to transform gradle-8.2.2.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.2) to match attributes {artifactType=jar, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.internal.hierarchy-collected=false, org.gradle.internal.instrumented=instrumented-external-dependency, org.gradle.jvm.environment=standard-jvm, org.gradle.jvm.version=11, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime, org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type=jvm}.       > Could not find gradle-8.2.2.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.2).         Searched in the following locations:             https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/8.2.2/gradle-8.2.2.jar    > Failed to transform builder-8.2.2.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder:8.2.2) to match attributes {artifactType=jar, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.internal.hierarchy-collected=false, org.gradle.internal.instrumented=instrumented-external-dependency, org.gradle.jvm.environment=standard-jvm, org.gradle.jvm.version=11, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime, org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type=jvm}.       > Could not find builder-8.2.2.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder:8.2.2).         Searched in the following locations:             https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/8.2.2/builder-8.2.2.jar

I've tried reinstalling Gradle myself, and I've also completely reinstalled Android Studio. None of that helped.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVg68.png)

Comment: Something's wrong in your `build.gradle` file, which you haven't shared. Please share code as text and format as code, not as an image.

Comment: Please also preserve the linebreaks rather than stringing it together into one line; it's very hard to read like this.

Comment: There are [various questions about this error](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+%22Could+not+find+builder%22); I've linked one specifically as a possible duplicate, but if that doesn't help, there are many more with suggestions at that search.

Comment: After looking at the questions you suggested, I first cleared the Gradle cache and that didn't help. After that I deleted the .gradle folder itself. After that Android studio started to automatically download the .zip archive for Gradle, but after downloading it just shows a "Read timed out" error.